# SSISDB - How to find the number of rows read from a table

Tags: ssis

I am using SQL Server 2019 and am using the SSISDB database to extract the execution progress of the SSIS packages:

```
select top 10 
from \[SSISDB\].\[catalog\].\[operation_messages\]
```

1. Records written to a SQL table:

I can find the number of rows written to a SQL table from SSISDB tables.

e.g. Data Flow For INSERTING Test records:Information: "INSERT ERRORS into Test_ERRORS" wrote 1 rows.

2. Records read from a SQL table:

I am unable to find a way to check the number of rows read from a SQL table by an OLE DB Source task.

I can use the Row Count task and manually insert the number of rows read into a table. But I wanted to know whether SSISDB has this information logged when the package is executed.

Does anyone know how I can get the stats on number of rows read from OLE DB Source task that reads a SQL table from SSISDB database?

Thanks,

Anand